# I need help debugging a java guessing game app

Tags: java, debugging, for-loop, nested-loops

I made this guessing game, but I found a bug in it and I don't know how to fix it. Maybe you guys can help?

the problem is, is that i will enter ONLY 9 wrong numbers, but then it will tell me I guessed 10 times. Which I didn't.

If you find any other bugs, could you tell me how to fix those too?
AND if you can tell me any tips/techniques that I could use next time that would be great.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int number_to_guess = 3;
    int guess;
    //int number_of_guesses = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Hello, please enter a number between 1 and 10. You only have 10 guesses, so be be smart!!");




    for(int number_of_guesses = 1; number_of_guesses<=10;){
        guess = input.nextInt();
        if (guess >=1 && guess <=10){//is it between 1 and 10

            if(guess == number_to_guess){//is it the right number
                number_of_guesses++;//increase guess number
                System.out.println("Congradulations!!! You guessed the number in " + number_of_guesses + " tries");
                break;//exit the loop
            }

            else{//if its not the right number, then try again
                System.out.println("I'm sorry. Thats not it. Please try again.");
                number_of_guesses++;
                if (number_of_guesses == 10){
                    System.out.println("I'm sorry, but it appears you have guessed 10 times and didn't get the right number. The number was " + number_to_guess);

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        else{//invalid number entry

            System.out.println("I'm sorry, but your number that you have enter is invalid. Please make sure it is between 1 and 10");
            number_of_guesses--;//the count will go up, even though the guessed an invalid number, so set it back to what it was before
        }
    }



}
```

}

Comment: change: `number_of_guesses<=10` to `number_of_guesses<=11`

Comment: You use the word "debug." So why not step through with a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

You neef to move this out of scope, since 10 is still valid

if (number_of_guesses == 10){ System.out.println("I'm sorry, but it appears you have guessed 10 times and didn't get the right number. The number was " + number_to_guess); break; }